# How make waiting result from loop data query firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I've tried to get detailed data for each member from the member list, but it's not optimal because it always returns undefined, so I use settimeout to wait for the load time of the data being retrieved.

i have tried to make the return waiting the result data from loop query

this my code :

```
database().ref(`/group/${groupid}`)
    .on("value", snapshot => {
      let data_1 = snapshot.val();
      let members = '';
      let i = 0;
      for(let memberid in data_1) {
        i++;
        database().ref(`/members/${memberid}`)
        .once("value", snapshot => {
          let data_2 = snapshot.val();
          members += '"'+memberid+'":{"uid":"'+data_2.uid+'","name":"'+data_2.name+'","avatar":"'+data_2.avatar+'"},';
        }) 
      } 
      let duration = parseInt(i)*125;
        setTimeout(() => {    
          let resmembers = '{'+members.slice(0, -1)+'}'; 
          let membersobj = JSON.parse(resmembers);
          return membersobj;
        },parseInt(duration))
      })
```

how make the return waiting the result from loop without settimeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all()` to handle this like this... I've also used `Object.assign()` to convert array into a single object

```
database().ref(`/group/${groupid}`).on("value", async snapshot => {
  let data_1 = snapshot.val();
  let memberPromises = [];
  for (let memberid in data_1) {
    let memberPromise = database().ref(`/members/${memberid}`).once("value").then(snapshot => {
      let data_2 = snapshot.val();
      return {
        uid: data_2.uid,
        name: data_2.name,
        avatar: data_2.avatar
      };
    });
    memberPromises.push(memberPromise);
  }
  let members = await Promise.all(memberPromises);
  let membersobj = Object.assign({}, members);
  return membersobj;
});
```

Hope This Helps...